java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources with GraalVM
I'm running a Spring Boot application with GraalVM and encountering the following error, even though the class is included in the reflect-config.json file.
Error Message:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources with GraalVM

Stack-trace
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/LettuceConnectionConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redisConnectionFactory' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lettuceClientResources' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/LettuceConnectionConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources]: Factory method 'lettuceClientResources' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1609)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1573)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1492)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1349)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)\r\n\t... 109 common frames omitted\r\nCaused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lettuceClientResources' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/LettuceConnectionConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources]: Factory method 'lettuceClientResources' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)\r\n\t... 126 common frames omitted\r\nCaused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources]: Factory method 'lettuceClientResources' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)\r\n\t... 140 common frames omitted\r\nCaused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.LettuceConnectionConfiguration.lettuceClientResources(LettuceConnectionConfiguration.java:71)\r\n\tat java.base@22.0.2/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)\r\n\t... 141 common frames omitted\r\n"} 
We are using the following command to auto-generate the GraalVM reflection configurations:
-Dspring.aot.enabled=true -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=./config

This command successfully added the following JSON entry in reflect-config.json:
{
  "name": "io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources",
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods": true,
  "methods": [
    {
      "name": "addressResolverGroup",
      "parameterTypes": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "builder",
      "parameterTypes": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "commandLatencyPublisherOptions",
      "parameterTypes": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "commandLatencyRecorder",
      "parameterTypes": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "computationThreadPoolSize",
      "parameterTypes": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "create",
      "parameterTypes": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "create",
      "parameterTypes": [
        "io.lettuce.core.resource.ThreadFactoryProvider"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "dnsResolver",
      "parameterTypes": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "eventBus",
      "parameterTypes": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "eventExecutorGroup",
      "parameterTypes": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "eventLoopGroupProvider",
      "parameterTypes": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "ioThreadPoolSize",
      "parameterTypes": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "mutate",
      "parameterTypes": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "nettyCustomizer",
      "parameterTypes": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "reconnectDelay",
      "parameterTypes": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "shutdown",
      "parameterTypes": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "shutdown",
      "parameterTypes": [
        "long",
        "long",
        "java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "socketAddressResolver",
      "parameterTypes": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "timer",
      "parameterTypes": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "tracing",
      "parameterTypes": [
        
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Question:
What could be causing the NoClassDefFoundError for DefaultClientResources despite it being specified in reflect-config.json? Are there any additional configurations or dependencies I should check when integrating GraalVM with Spring Boot and Lettuce?

Can you give a better stacktrace ? This one is just not readable. Use the triple back-quote
